# How can I remove a condition from a collection

Tags: magento2, collection, sql, plugin

I tried to use two methods to reset or clear the collection but it didn't work.
I am working with the category collection on which I want to remove this part of the condition : `(e.created_in <= '1685690220') AND (e.updated_in > '1685690220')`.

Here is the full query generated by the collection :

```
SELECT `e`.`entity_id`, `ss`.`id` FROM `catalog_category_entity` AS `e`
 LEFT JOIN `staging_update` AS `ss` ON e.created_in = ss.id WHERE ((e.entity_id IN ('76')) AND (e.created_in ='1685690220') AND (ss.is_rollback IS NULL)) AND (e.created_in <= '1685690220') AND (e.updated_in > '1685690220');
```

Here is the plugin code I tried :

```
<?php

namespace custommodule\ScheduleContentNotifier\Plugin;

use Magento\CatalogStaging\Model\CategoryApplier;
use custommodule\ScheduleContentNotifier\Helper\Email;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Category;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Flat\State;
use Magento\Framework\Indexer\CacheContext;
use Magento\Framework\Indexer\IndexerRegistry;
use Magento\Staging\Model\StagingApplierInterface;
use Magento\Staging\Api\UpdateRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory;

class PluginCategoryApplier
{
    protected $emailHelper;

    protected $_categoryCollection;

    /**
     * @var UpdateRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $updateRepository;

    /**
     * @var State
     */
    private $flatState;

    /**
     * @var IndexerRegistry
     */
    private $indexerRegistry;

    /**
     * @var CacheContext
     */
    private $cacheContext;

    /**
     * @param State $flatState
     * @param IndexerRegistry $indexerRegistry   
     * @param CacheContext $cacheContext
     */
    public function __construct(
        State $flatState,
        IndexerRegistry $indexerRegistry,
        CacheContext $cacheContext,
        CollectionFactory $categoryCollection,
        UpdateRepositoryInterface $updateRepository,
        Email $emailHelper,
    ) {
        $this->updateRepository = $updateRepository;
        $this->emailHelper = $emailHelper;
        $this->flatState = $flatState;
        $this->indexerRegistry = $indexerRegistry;
        $this->cacheContext = $cacheContext;
        $this->_categoryCollection = $categoryCollection;
    }

    public function aroundExecute(CategoryApplier $subject, callable $proceed, array $entityIds)
    {
        if ($entityIds) {
        $currentVersionId = $this->updateRepository->getVersionMaxIdByTime(
                strtotime("now")
            );
            $select = $this->_categoryCollection->create()->clear()->getSelect()->reset(\Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::WHERE)->columns(['entity_id'])
                ->joinLeft(['ss' => 'staging_update'], 'e.created_in = ss.id', ['id'])
                ->where('e.entity_id IN (?)', $entityIds)
                ->where('e.created_in =?', $currentVersionId)
                ->where('ss.is_rollback IS NULL');
            $result = $this->_categoryCollection
                ->getConnection()
                ->fetchOne($select);
            if (isset($result) && $result) {
                $this->emailHelper->sendEmail();
            }            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add more details about what you are trying to achieve ? The `CategoryApplier` class doesn't seem to generate this kind of query on its own. What action is generating it, and why do you need to remove this specific part of the query ?

Answer (score 0):

Using reset, like below

```
$collection->clear()->getSelect()->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::WHERE)->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::ORDER);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this plugin

```
<?php

namespace custommodule\ScheduleContentNotifier\Plugin;

use Magento\CatalogStaging\Model\CategoryApplier;
use custommodule\ScheduleContentNotifier\Helper\Email;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Category;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Flat\State;
use Magento\Framework\Indexer\CacheContext;
use Magento\Framework\Indexer\IndexerRegistry;
use Magento\Staging\Model\StagingApplierInterface;
use Magento\Staging\Api\UpdateRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory;

class PluginCategoryApplier
{
    protected $emailHelper;

    protected $_categoryCollection;

    /**
     * @var UpdateRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $updateRepository;

    /**
     * @var State
     */
    private $flatState;

    /**
     * @var IndexerRegistry
     */
    private $indexerRegistry;

    /**
     * @var CacheContext
     */
    private $cacheContext;

    /**
     * @param State $flatState
     * @param IndexerRegistry $indexerRegistry   
     * @param CacheContext $cacheContext
     */
    public function __construct(
        State $flatState,
        IndexerRegistry $indexerRegistry,
        CacheContext $cacheContext,
        CollectionFactory $categoryCollection,
        UpdateRepositoryInterface $updateRepository,
        Email $emailHelper
    ) {
        $this->updateRepository = $updateRepository;
        $this->emailHelper = $emailHelper;
        $this->flatState = $flatState;
        $this->indexerRegistry = $indexerRegistry;
        $this->cacheContext = $cacheContext;
        $this->_categoryCollection = $categoryCollection;
    }

    public function aroundExecute(CategoryApplier $subject, callable $proceed, array $entityIds)
    {
        if ($entityIds) {
            $currentVersionId = $this->updateRepository->getVersionMaxIdByTime(strtotime("now"));
            $select = $this->_categoryCollection->create()->clear()->getSelect()
                ->reset(\Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)
                ->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::WHERE)
                ->columns(['entity_id'])
                ->joinLeft(['ss' => 'staging_update'], 'e.created_in = ss.id', ['id'])
                ->where('e.entity_id IN (?)', $entityIds)
                ->where('e.created_in =?', $currentVersionId)
                ->where('ss.is_rollback IS NULL');

            // Remove the unwanted condition from the query
            $select->where('e.created_in > ?', '1685690220');

            $result = $this->_categoryCollection
                ->getConnection()
                ->fetchOne($select);

            if (isset($result) && $result) {
                $this->emailHelper->sendEmail();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding `$select->where(...)` will just add again this new condition, it will not remove it.

Answer (score 0):

> **Try this code**

```
$wherePart = $result->getSelect()->getPart(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::WHERE);

print_r($wherePart); // You can remove any where ny using unset($wherePart[index]);

$result->getSelect()->setPart(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::WHERE,$wherePart);
```

**Working Example Code**

```
<?php

namespace vendoreName\ModuleName\Plugin;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer;

class LayerPlugin
{
    protected $request;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
    ) {
       $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function afterGetProductCollection(Layer $subject, $result)
    {
        $wherePart = $result->getSelect()->getPart(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::WHERE);
        if((count($wherePart) >= 2) && (count($this->request->getParams()) >= 2)) {
            unset($wherePart[0]);
            if (isset($wherePart[1])) {
                $wherePart[1] = str_replace('AND', '', $wherePart[1]);
                $result->getSelect()->setPart(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::WHERE,$wherePart);
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }

}
```